# Nesting Expressions

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, expression

I have and expression:

```
=UCASE(Fields!MotherFullName.Value)​
```

and an expression:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!MotherFullName.Value) ,"-",Fields!MotherFullName.Value)
```

I want to nest them into one expression since they are operating on the same value, what must I do?

Comment: `ISNOTHING`? `Fields!`? Are you sure this has anything at all to do with T-SQL / Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: This might be MS-Access... or some VBA thing...

Comment: Actually you should Tag this SSRS Reports. These are RDLC reports

Comment: all the tagged groups are relevant

Comment: @scsimon If this question is about SSRS expressions, then it has nothing to do with Excel or VBA. SSRS expressions are VB.NET AFAIK, not VBA - although I'll concede that the syntax does look very much similar.

Comment: If it is VB.NET, the expression form should be preferred to IIF and ISNOTHING, i.e. If(... Is Nothing, ..., ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code and taking a pass on evaluating the syntax...

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!MotherFullName.Value) ,"-",UCASE(Fields!MotherFullName.Value)​)
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(UCASE(Fields!MotherFullName.Value)​) ,"-",UCASE(Fields!MotherFullName.Value))
```

should work, but I'd Advise you to Create Additional fields in your report and they use them to arrive at what you need, since the fields you dont include will not be displayed.

Also, Make sure you are making your edits in the expression window, not directly on your reports.

Answer (score 0):

I finished creating the report above and it is working well, but when I upload it into the CRM Dynamics online, it is greyed out as shown in the picture bellow: What must I do?

[image]